# Is there a blue rock equivalent in the Womb?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac

In Binding of Isaac, the earlier levels have blue rocks that when bombed yield usable items and/or chests. In the womb, the rocks are red and I haven't seen any that stand out from the rest. Is there a blue rock equivalent in the Womb that when bombed will give the player items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The X rocks do exist in the womb. The trouble is they look identical to all other rocks, there is no x to define them, or even a different shade of colour. The only way to tell that you even found one is by watching the items pop out of it when it's destroyed.

You're not going to find them reliably, and unless you have more bombs than you can count (like from getting the skeleton key and then the Bombs are keys pill), you're not exactly going to blow up every rock in the room.

In the womb, you're most often going to find the rocks by accident, when trying to damage an enemy, or get to some other treasure that's blocked off by rocks.

Comment: They're identical? No wonder I haven't seen them...can anyone confirm? We should correct the wiki if so, it says they're "very difficult to notice" which implies it's possible to differentiate them

Comment: @BenBrocka If they're not identical, then there's a difference of like one pixel or something, because I've tested it at one point in one of those rooms that have only rocks with one item in the middle, and I didn't notice any difference between any of the rocks (well apart from the normal difference between the womb rocks) and one of them popped some items out.

Comment: This is not exactly helpful to the answer, but if you use The Nail, you destroy all rocks just by walking over them. When I have The Nail in the womb, it is helpful to always walk over the rocks after using it and cleaning a room, in order to find the X rocks.

Answer (score 1):

These are actually called [X rocks](http://bindingofisaac.wikia.com/wiki/Secrets#X_Rocks). They're in the Womb too, but harder to notice. You're looknig for the darker tone and the X-marks-the-spot mark.

Normal ones look like this (from the wiki):

[image]

The womb ones look different obviously...can't find any pictures though, has anyone else? People on the Wiki have expressed their difficulty finding them and I've never found/noticed one myself.

Answer (score 0):

You can find "X rocks", just look to lower-left side of all rocks, they have little line. It's not easy to find it in the first time you look at it, you will notice it after a few seconds

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a difference but there is one thing i calling filter tinted rocks issue while you playing with firter you cant tell difference between marked and standart rock but without filter you can see a line in bottom right corner and tinted rocks have perpendicular line which makes curved x and you can actually see it ( and yes dots and commas suck) https://images.app.goo.gl/6jEtUCS6d4xCU5eXA sorry i am on mobile